# Is it possible to block messages sent from SendMessage() calls?

Tags: c++, winapi, sendmessage

I have a a block of code that I suspect is sending messages via `SendMessage()` function.
For debug purposes, I would like any message sent using `SendMessage()` in this block of code to no be sent, much like `blockSignals()` works in Qt.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Why don`t you just comment out the SendMessage() calls?

Comment: The code block I'm talking about is "big", meaning it uses objects that use other objects etc... at very deep level. So, I don't see the SendMessage() calls being made. That's why I would like to be able to block them for a defined scope.

Comment: You could hook the `SendMessage` function on entry to that block of code, and have your replacement function just drop the messages on the floor. Or you could add an "ignore" flag to your message loop. Turn on the ignore flag on when you want to disable message processing, and then re-enable it when you're done. The risk is that you'll also fail to get system messages, etc.

Comment: @JimMischel: if the target window is owned by the same thread that is calling `SendMessage()`, the message will not go through the message loop at all. This is clearly documented.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Thanks for the reminder. It's been too long since I worked at that level. I wonder, then, if it's possible to hook `SendMessage`. Well, it's *possible*, but whether it's practical is another question entirely.

Answer (score 0):

You can use next in top you program:

```
#define DEBUG
```

or if release

```
#define NDEBUG
```

Next in text you program:

```
#ifndef DEBUG
    SendMessage();
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't comment out the SendMessage() calls and you just want to see the content of some messages you can use Spy++ (if you use Visual Studio)  otherwise you can install a hook using SetWindowsHookEx(). If you have access to the message loop you can put some filters there.

Comment: In-context sent messages aren't dispatched by the message loop. The system directly calls into the window procedure for in-context sent messages.

Comment: SetWindowsHookEx() can can in-context sent messages, though.